# when register in magento2 getting no entity

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2.3, registration

when I'm registering magento2 getting an error like

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with email = prasad@value22.com, websiteId = 1

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with email = prasad@value22.com, websiteId = 1
```

file path /vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository.php line 300
can anyone help me.

Comment: If you search the admin panel is that email a valid customer? if so check you server variables max_input_vars and make sure that it is set to something like 300000 also check your post data size